# Ruby on rails global cach

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need some global variable on my server that will always be there
Is there a built in way to use some global cache on a rails server?

I'm looking for a query cache that will last for an hour.

Is it recommended?

Comment: Are you looking for a read only global variable, or something that is mutable? If it is something that is mutable, does it need to be shared across requests? Please add more specifics as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always put variables I want to access everywhere into the `environments/{production,development,..}.rb` files, depending of the environment. If you want some fast datastore, which needs to store some more complex data, I would suggest [redis](http://redis.io/). If redis is to heavy for your use case you can also use the [Rails Caching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can always add an app specific yaml file that you load from a file in initializers

in initializers:

raw_config = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")

APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(raw_config)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys

then you can access APP_CONFIG from anywhere in your app
APP_CONFIG[:some_var]